# Stuck on RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am stuck in redirecting my urls. I think i am almost there but can't oversee what i am missing. When i test the redirect is goes to the correct url, but sticks the old url behinde the new url.

This is where i got stuck:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=uk&page=page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/page/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=fr&page=page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/page/ [L,R=301]    

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=uk&page=about
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/about/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=uk&page=about
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/about/ [L,R=301]    

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=uk&page=news
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/info/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=fr&page=news
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain/info/ [L,R=301]
```

I am also scared i get stuck with a big htaccess file if i do all redirects individual. Would that slow things down?

Lang=nl, uk, us, fr all go to the same page.
not all page= got the same pagename after the change.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have specific redirects first where page name is not same as target followed by a single rule where query parameter `page` has same value as the target URI. So your code can be shortened to these 2 rules only.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=(fr|uk|us|nl)&page=news
RewriteRule ^ /info/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=(fr|uk|us|nl)&page=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: No issues, we all started a new users at some point of time :)